# Name not defined error in python django

Tags: python, django

```
import csv
import io
import re

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic

from ...forms import CsvUploadForm

import pandas as pd


class CsvImportView(generic.base.View):
    def getemailcolumn(self, sample):
        for key, val in sample:
           print(key, val)
           if re.match("^.+@([?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$", val[0]) is not None:
              return key
        return None


    def post(self, request):
        form = CsvUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
           fieldnames = ['first_name', 'email', 'last_name']

           csv = pd.read_csv(request.FILES['csv'])

           sample =csv.head();

           emailColumn = getemailcolumn(sample)

           return HttpResponse(sample)
        else:
          ...
          ...
```

when the post method is getting executed, i am getting a name not defined error

> name 'getemailcolumn' is not defined

what am i missing?

Comment: `self.getemailcolumn(sample)`? Also, please indent your code properly for a better visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`getemailcolumn()`** is a **instance method**. It could be accessible through `self` or `class instance`. In your case, you are trying to access it from another instance method. So it should be as,

`emailColumn = self.getemailcolumn(sample)`

Answer (score -2):

You need to indent the get and post methods because python thinks they are not part of the class CsvImportView. So indent them inline with the function you are calling.

EDIT:
Okay it needs to be self.getmailcolumn instead of just the function name

Comment: indentation is not an issue here, its SO copy-paste problem. adjusted the indent. But your answer is not correct